# Windows 8 Built-in Back-Up Utility

Tags: windows-8, hard-drive, backup

I have a Western Digital Passport 1TB. Windows 8.1 does not recognise it as a device for backing up data or making a windows image on it. 2 months ago these features worked fine but after I changed my internal hard drive and reinstalled windows everything changed. I can see it in explorer and use it as a normal hard drive, but when I go to System and Security -> File History -> System Image Backup I can't see my drive as a valid device. If I plug my 32 GB flash drive Windows shows it as a valid device and I can create a backup on it. The HDD is not even half way full and it's file system is NTFS so I don't see where the problem is

Comment: Is the HDD set for Quick Disconnect?  When you plug in the HDD, does Windows give you an "eject" for it?  the System Image Backup usually needs the whole hard drive in a specific format.  Have you tried formatting and/or removing all partitions from the HDD and see if the Backup will use it?

Comment: Yes I tried to set it as a static drive, there was a comment that I will have to use the Safely Remove Hardware function.

Comment: I will try to fit all my data on my internal hard drive but it will be a difficult task because I have a lot of data that I need on that hard drive and my internal one is only 320 GB